# Cannot download packages through pip for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, biopython

I used command prompt to download Jupyter notebook, and for some reason I can't import certain libraries like numpy, pandas, or bio. Here is the error message I get when I try to install bio:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\bamfo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bamfo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d04zmt2\\biopython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bamfo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d04zmt2\\biopython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bamfo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7wph4w5a\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\bamfo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\biopython'
         cwd: C:\Users\bamfo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3d04zmt2\biopython\
    Complete output (698 lines):
    ----
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\bamfo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bamfo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d04zmt2\\biopython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bamfo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d04zmt2\\biopython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bamfo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7wph4w5a\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\bamfo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\biopython' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\bamfo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: I did not add the complete output because it was too long for Stack

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing the build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ like the error message suggests?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Comment: @brice, yes I downloaded Microsoft Visual and still the error message comes up, even when I restart the kernel